# php make unique hash of rss description

Tags: php, hash, rss, duplicates

im using php to create a sorta rss aggregator that stores data from multiple site rss feeds into a mysql database. since articles could be duplicated on many websites, i want to avoid this. ive been told you could use hashing to make unique hashes based on content of rss[description + title]. Now which hashing algorithm is fastest and produces less characters that i can use for comparison to avoid duplicates.

Thanx in advance

Comment: There are lots available. But the less number of characters generated by the hash function, the more likely you'll have collisions in your identifiers. Be certain about that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sprintf('%u',crc32()) produces 4,294,967,296 combinations, and it's shorter than md5 or sha1. it's only 32 bits wide.

Comment: You should pass the string as the argument of `crc32`, of course.

Comment: it's the OP's option. he can use dechex(sprintf('%u',crc32()) if he wants a hex string, or just a plain left-zero-padded for pure decimal digits.

Comment: @DanielL... does that output an integer or string?

Comment: Remember as @stillstanding wrote, "the less number of characters generated by the hash function, the more likely you'll have collisions in your identifiers. Be certain about that.". MD5 is 128-bit so gives way more identifiers and much much lesser chance of collisions.

Comment: how about similar_text. is this worth doing

Comment: @Sir Lojik: Returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid false duplicates you should use a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm like SHA-1 or MD5.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is fastest and produces hash that is 32 characters long.

```
<?php
$hash = md5($description . $title);
?>
```

I used it in my RSS parser for exactly same purpose. And it works like a charm.

Comment: thanx for all your answers, but i think i'll take shammittomars answer as its 32 chars long, uses md5 and he understood my question. and has gone thru similar problem